# How can I create a new tab then update it with a google chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to create an extension for chrome where if I enter a search term and click a button, it will open a new tab on twitter with that search. Then, if I enter another search term into the extension, it will just refresh the already opened tab to the new search url.

I know I need chrome.tabs.update and chrome.tabs.create, I just can't seem to get it to function.

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
      const searchButton = document.getElementById('searchButton');
    
      searchButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        const query = searchInput.value;
    
        let tabId = -1;
    
        function createTab(tab) {
          const tabDetails = {
            url: "https://twitter.com/search?q=" + query,
            active: true,
            index: tab.index + 1
          };
    
          if (tabId == -1) {
            chrome.tabs.create(tabDetails, tab => {
              tabId = tab.id;
            });
          } else {
            // check if tab is still around
            chrome.tabs.get(tabId, (tab) => {
              if (tab) {
                chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, tabDetails);
              } else {
                chrome.tabs.create(tabDetails, tab => {
                  tabId = tab.id;
                });
              }
            });
          }
        }
    
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
          const currentTab = tabs[0];
          createTab(currentTab);
        });
      });
    });
```

This is what I have so far, but it is only creating a new tab each time. I am very new to javascript and chrome extensions, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Move the line `let tabId = -1;` outside of the button listener function, because it is been reset every time the button is clicked.

Comment: Opening a new tab from the action popup will automatically close the popup and terminate its scripts immediately, so none of your subsequent code will run. You can open the tab as inactive i.e. with `active: false` or you can replace the current tab by using chrome.tabs.update() instead of create()